# Is it the content or the source of an obligation that determines whether it is moral or aesthetic?

Tags: ethics, aesthetics, value-theory

Is it the content or the source of an obligation that determines whether it is moral or aesthetic?

Consider the following statement reflecting a perceived obligation: "I must save the beautiful painting from the burning art gallery". Suppose the reason for this obligation arising is moral, e.g., the joy which spectators experience from observing the painting is intrinsically good, and therefore it should be saved for it to continue as a source of joy and thus good.

Is this obligation to save the painting then a moral obligation (on account of the source of the obligation) or an aesthetic obligation (on account of the contents of the obligation - to save a painting, an aesthetic object)?

Comment: nice question, thanks. i would call it a moral obligation, but don't have much to add beyond that

Comment: well, we could then ask, what is the source of a moral obligation? Is the source of a moral obligation moral? It gets a bit messy.

Comment: There's a good deal of ambiguity/ambivalence, here, but you *are* asking a good question (I'm not accusing you of ambiguity, since you clearly disambiguate the terms of your question). For example, then: sometimes in moral philosophy, we treat *any* use of terms like "obligation," "should," "norm," etc. as having moral force; other times we speak of instrumental vs. moral, but either way still practical, reasoning. Sometimes we even separate "moral" from "ethical," which is harder to justify even on linguistic grounds.

Comment: Moral is not subjective. You are not obligated nor is all humans obligated to save the beautiful painting. So of it is not moral we can rule that  out.

Comment: why would we not be so obligated @Logikal ? I'm fairly sure it's an obligation... maybe if we were in aesthetic rapture as we saved it haha?

Comment: @return, we are not obligated because there are several other things human beings would hold as higher priority.  Human beings can likely live without or with only a handful of aesthetic beauties.

Comment: Any public content such as your painting in gallery can be discussed, analyzed and perhaps valued a lot aesthetically by people in the same way as someone's act as a performed content can be discussed (aesthetically) by you, but it by no means the content is necessarily morality-related. It's well-known only agent can have morality. If you adopt cognitivism in meta-ethics it's always the source cognition of the agent matters. Per Baudrillard the difference between sign and symbol is very important thus a painting is not just an objective sign and may contain significant subjective meanings...

Comment: there's probably a useful answer here about exchange and use value. if we are motivated by the use value, then perhaps it is at least more aesthetic a decision than it otherwise would be

Comment: I see what a "moral obligation" is, but what is it you call an "aesthetic obligation"?

Comment: The nature of obligation is determined by its content, but the content here is moral, not aesthetic, to save an item of value to others (or of "intrinsic" value). That the value happens to be aesthetic in this case is incidental. It would make little difference to the nature of the obligation if the item was instead a religious relic or a marvel of engineering. There is an influential view that aesthetic obligations do not exist at all, the obligatory force always derives from morality, see [Kubala, 
Aesthetic obligations](https://compass.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/phc3.12712).

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping what an esthetic obligation would look like. Can you give an unambiguous example of one?

Comment: This is why Salvador Dali didn't build an art museum.

Answer (score 1):

> The aesthetic value of an object is the value it possesses in virtue
> of its capacity to provide aesthetic gratification (Beardsley 1982)

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aesthetic-concept/

So, in your example, you are being motivated by its aesthetic value, at least in some senses as it is conceived. Does that mean we are not **also** motivated by utility or duty, etc.? If so, then prima facie, if we are motivated by duty we are ***only*** motivated by duty. Which sounds wrong, even if it isn't

> Many critics of Kant have thought that Kant is committed to the view
> that a good will is only motivated by duty

So I would start there.